# Оформление множества неполных цитат

Tags: пунктуация, абзац, цитаты

*Как правильно оформить предложение с множеством неполных цитат:*

> Вот пара выжимок из газеты: "...Центром внимания стал герой..."(?)
> "...За прошедший год фермеры..."(?) "...Случай на улице
> Красноармейская..."(?) и так далее. Короче говоря, занимательный
> выпуск!

*Нужно/можно ли переносить каждую цитату на следующий абзац (в случае, если цитаты довольно большие)? Какие знаки препинания использовать?*

Answer (score 1):

Если верить 142-му параграфу, то нужна строчная буква:  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

> Вот пара выжимок из газеты: «...центром внимания стал герой...», «...за прошедший год фермеры...», «...случай на улице Красноармейская...» и так далее. Короче говоря, занимательный выпуск!

P. S. Перенос возможен.